# Swift: How to update data in Core Data when didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have searched for other questions and asking this because I couldn't find anything suitable for me.

I have some data in core data and want to update it when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. this is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

var todo = [NSManagedObject]()
var JSON = Data.sharedInstance

@IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.JSON.JSONData { 
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        self.TableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedobject = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ToDo")
    do {
        let results = try managedobject.executeFetchRequest(fetchrequest)
        todo = results as! [NSManagedObject]

     } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    TableView.reloadData()

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return todo.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

   let state = todo[indexPath.row].valueForKey("state") as? Float
    print(state)


    if state == 0.0 {
    cell.textLabel?.text = todo[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name") as? String
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Now, When the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called, I want to update the key   "**state**" that can be seen in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to 1.0

Can someone one please me on how to update the value of "**state**". Thanks

Comment: Did you try `let object = todo[indexPath.row]
object.setValue(yourValue, forKey: "state")` and then save with the main context.

Comment: Same way you'd update Core Data in any other situation.

Comment: @Santosh should I add the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @TomHarrington which way?

Comment: There's nothing about `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that makes updating Core Data different from updating it in other methods. Is the real question about how to update Core Data *in general*, not just here?

Comment: @TomHarrington I have managed to update it. But after updating it is supposed to go to other view controller, but then it is not being displayed in both the view controller, How do I delete in the present table view?

Comment: Between your question and your comments I'm not actually sure what problem you're trying to solve here. Maybe it's updating an object? Or maybe deleting one? Or maybe it has something to do with transitioning to another view controller?

Comment: @TomHarrington my actual issue is Basically, I have a tabbed application. the "state" attribute has either 0 or 1. If it is in 0 it will be in tab 0, if it is 1 will be in the tab 1. So, when user taps on the cell, i.e when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called I want "state" 0 to be updated to 1 in the core data, for which I asked this question. Now, I somehow managed to get it, but as I told you, It is being displayed in both the tabs now and If I delete the row in 0 tab, it is automatically getting deleted in tab 1 also. This is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method something like `reloadData` and move the code for fetching object from `viewDidAppear`. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, do something like:

```
todo[indexPath.row].updateValue(NSNumber(float: 1.0), forKey: "state") // Sample syntax only. Not sure if it is correct.
managedObjectContext.save()

reloadData()
```

Comment: I have managed to update it. But after updating it is supposed to go to other view controller, but then it is not being displayed in both the view controller, How do I delete in the present table view?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your model and Core Data related, but the idea is update the model when `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` called, and tell the tableView to reloadData().

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     // Update in todo array.
     // Save it, even I don't recommend to save it here,
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Usually, data could be saved when app enters background. Or some other place which will not be called constantly, since save will be a costing job to do.

Comment: Thanks antonio. I have managed to update it. But after updating it is supposed to go to other view controller, but then it is not being displayed in both the view controller, How do I delete in the present table view?

Comment: How do you manage to go to other ViewController, `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)
`?

Comment: Usually, we save the data in one VC, then load the data from another. @raja

Comment: Basically, I have a tabbed application. the "state" attribute has either 0 or 1. If it is in 0 it will be in tab 0, if it is 1 will be in the tab 1. So, when user taps on the cell, i.e when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called I want "state" 0 to be updated to 1 in the core data, for which I asked this question. Now, I somehow managed to get it, but as I told you, It is being displayed in both the tabs now and If I delete the row in 0 tab, it is automatically getting deleted in tab 1 also. This is my issue.